# How to go back (ctrl+z) in vi/vim

Tags: vim, vi, back, undo, undo-redo

In normal text editors [with all due respect to Vim] there is a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> when you have done something nasty and want to return to the previous version of the text. Like BACK button in Word. I wonder how can you achieve this behaviour in Vim.

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Undo_and_Redo

Comment: The Vim documentation is also very good - `:help undo` will find you your answer on this, for example.

Comment: before diving into vim completely, I suggest you go through the [(interactive) tutorial](http://www.openvim.com/tutorial.html)

Comment: Thank you all and sorry for this q. Must read more next time.

Comment: on linux, CTRL-Z in vi/vim/gvim mean escape to the console, or put this in the background. you then do whatever you want on the console and type fg (foreground) to bring you back into vim edit session.

Answer (score 300, accepted):

You can use the `u` button to undo the last modification. (And <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to redo it).

Read more about it at: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Undo_and_Redo

Comment: I map U to redo so I can undo / redo quickly, the entire edit history if necessary, in vimrc: nnoremap U <C-R>

Answer (score 17):

Just in *normal mode* press:

- <kbd>u</kbd> - ***u**ndo*,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> - ***r**edo* changes which were undone (*undo* the *undos*).

[Undo and Redo](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Undo_and_Redo)

Comment: I know that most of my answer is duplicated with those already present, **but** the value added of my answer is redo as `Ctrl + r` (lower case `r`) based on the documentation. Nobody before put it here. In addition, I tried to make the answer as clearly as possible.

Answer (score 15):

The answer, `u`, (and many others) is in `$ vimtutor`.

Comment: up vote only because I've never heard of `vimtutor` before

Answer (score 9):

Here is a trick though. You can map the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> keys. 
This can be achieved by editing the `.vimrc` file. Add the following lines in the '.vimrc` file.

```
nnoremap <c-z> :u<CR>      " Avoid using this**
inoremap <c-z> <c-o>:u<CR>
```

This may not the a preferred way, but can be used.

** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is used in Linux to suspend the ongoing program/process.

Answer (score 0):

On a mac you can also use command Z and that will go undo.  I'm not sure why, but sometimes it stops, and if your like me and vimtutor is on the bottom of that long list of things you need to learn, than u can just close the window and reopen it and should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem right now and i solved it. You must not need it anymore so I write for others:

if you use **gvim** on **windows**, you just add this in your **_vimrc**:
`$VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim behave mswin`

else just use imap...